# I have problem with boxes and positioning in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, position

Hello I am trying to make website just for fun to see how much can I do with my knowledge for now! So I have a section where I want to put text (h1, p) in box. I tried to set background and everything and it looks okay but on different resolutions it looks different... And box size isn't same on every resolution. Here is my code from specific section!

This is HTML code:

```css
.services {
  background-color: rgb(36, 35, 35);
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
}

.services h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 27px;
}

.services p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.vpn {
  background-color: rgb(29, 28, 28);
  display: absolute;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 80px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.email {
  background-color: rgb(29, 28, 28);
  display: absolute;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <div class="vpn">
    <h1>VPN</h1>
    <p>We have free DDoS protected VPN servers in multiple countries in Europe with no speed limits.</p>
    <p>Our free VPN servers work on numrous streaming platforms.</p>
    <p>They can also work on both Android and iOS mobile phones with OpenVPN Connect!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="email">
    <h1>Custom E-Mail</h1>
    <p>We offer email inboxes on multiple domains.
      <p>We do not have limits, you can send and recieve as many emails as you like!</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `height:50vh`is probably not a good idea if font-size is itself always the same. min-height and a fluid font-size is maybe what you expected .. ?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post to be more specific. "Looks different" isn't a clear problem statement.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a poor method of layout. I would suggest that you try another method.

Comment: You want to avoid setting heights on elements unless you deal with overflow. For content you always want to see only use min-height to ensure something isn't too small.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't really understand your question, but I've noticed some mistakes in your css code.

**1.** There is no such thing as display: absolute, you may want to use display: flex, as if display is not set to flex - the justify-content, flex-direction properties simply won't work.

**2.** Instead of the display: absolute, maybe you wanted position: absolute.

It is required that you do some research before you post a question, so please do some.

**Here are some helpful links:**

***1.** [CSS Position Propery](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)*

***2.** [CSS FlexBox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)*

```
.vpn {
    background-color: rgb(29, 28, 28);
    display: absolute; // display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; // this property won't work without display: flex;
    justify-content: left; // this property won't work without display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 80px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.email {
    background-color: rgb(29, 28, 28);
    *display: absolute; // display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; // this property won't work without display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Check the following code out:

```css
 .services {
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   background-color: rgb(36, 35, 35);
   min-height: 50vh;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   color: white;
   display: flex;
}

.box{
  text-align: center;
  width: 40vw;
}

.services h1{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 27px;
}

.services p{
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>VPN</h1>
        <p>We have free DDoS protected VPN servers in multiple countries in Europe with no speed limits.
        <br>Our free VPN servers work on numrous streaming platforms.
        <br>They can also work on both Android and iOS mobile phones with OpenVPN Connect!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box ">
        <h1>Custom E-Mail</h1>
        <p>We offer email inboxes on multiple domains. 
        <br>We do not have limits, you can send and recieve as many emails as you like!</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Scolding is inappropriate. You should provide some explanation of your solution.